# 3D CAD Graphics Framework on OS X - Suggestions?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks, 3d, cad

I am looking to implement a 3D model viewer in my application. The application uses a series of interlinked plug-in objects, with user attributes, to contribute to the 3D form. (Basically a parametric design tool).

The plug-ins must communicate via a common, simple, protocol as they may also be user contributed and so I am looking for a suitable high level library/framework to generate the 3D model, preferably using a cocoa, that could either be exposed directly to the plug-in or via a traceable translation in the main program (allowing plug-ins to modify their contribution to the model)

It should be able to generate 3D forms from standard planes, surfaces and Boolean operations.

Does anyone have any experience with any such frameworks, such as perhaps Coin3D, and could advise suitability?

The icing on the cake would be reliable calculation of volumes and areas, for scientific calculations (Buoyancy, stability etc).

I have not decided on the distribution model, and would welcome suggestions of any licence format, but if the application is paid for it would be sub £30, and I do not have the capital to invest in expensive licensing seats.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a MacOS Framework, why not get started with the [OpenSCAD](http://openscad.org/).